# According to what method is 3D cursor's location in 3D View determined when left clicking?

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

When left clicking to position the 3D Cursor in 3D View, when in User Perspective view or User Ortho view, and more precisely when there's no object under the mouse, the position of the 3D Cursor looks random. I know it's not, there must be a way Blender determines it's location, but I can't find that out, is it a specified distance from view? In case it is, what is it, and can this distance be changed and manipulated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3D cursor moves in the plane facing the view you are in and intersecting its previous position.

Is you set up this configuration : a camera (bottom right), a plane (selected) 90° intersecting the camera view, you can notice this behaviour.
Go in the camera view using <kbd>0</kbd>, click somewhere to move the 3D cursor, and come back to the top view. The cursor will stay on the plane.

[image]

The distance of the plane is defined by the normal vector N of the view (N normalized) dot the camera-"prev cursor position" vector. Or if C is the camera, P the previous position, the distance is ||N.CP||

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to have a fixed distance, how is this distance determined? try to click in view, then zoom out, click again the same spot, it doesn't keep the same distance fro the view.

Comment: @Georges whatever the distance (zoom in or out) the cursor stays on the plane it was previously. If you rotate, another plane is "defined" the same way : face to the view (parallel) and intersecting the current position of the cursor

Comment: So the previous position of the cursor defines the distance of the plane from the camera. Nice, thank you, can you edit your answer to include this?

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your answer again, I see you explained this, but for some reason it wasn't clear to me, thank you.

Comment: your are welcome. I edited and added a bit more math definition of this distance